# Two Spring Boot apps setup with two ports throws 500 error when one uses RestTemplate to Post

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, vaadin

Ok I have STS 4 and building Spring Boot applications.  I want one to handle the GUI using Vaadin and it is working fine.  I have another that picks up an ActiveMQ Topic and creates a POST to the first one.  If I use POSTMAN to do the post, it works fine to the REST interface on the first app.  But when I run the second one and a Topic is detected and it tries to post to the first app REST interface, I get...

```
org.springframework.web.client.HttpServerErrorException$InternalServerError: 500 : [<!doctype html><html lang="en"><head><title>HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error</title><style type="text/css">body {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;} h1, h2, h3, b {color:white;background-colo... (6083 bytes)]
```

Further testing revealed that it is complaining because it is listening on the same port (8080) as the first one.

In my application.properties for the first app I have set

```
server.port=${PORT:8080}
vaadin.compatibilityMode = false
logging.level.org.atmosphere = warn
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
```

While in the second app I have set

```
server.port=${PORT:8081}
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
spring.jms.pub-sub-domain=true
active-mq.topic=personQBE
```

The offending code that is trying to POST is...

```
public void postResponses(Person person) {
    System.out.println("postResponses(Person person)");
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    headers.add("Accept", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.toString()); //Optional in case server sends back JSON data


    MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add("firstName", person.getFirstName());
    map.add("lastName", person.getLastName());
    map.add("alias", person.getAlias());
    map.add("dataSource", "BI");
    
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> entity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

    ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
    try {
        response = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080/person/add",
                                  HttpMethod.POST,
                                  entity,
                                  String.class);
    } catch (RestClientException e) {
        // TODO Log.error later
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("response:" + response);
    
}
```

I have read the blog post [Microservices with Spring](https://spring.io/blog/2015/07/14/microservices-with-spring) but not sure if I need to do this to solve my problem and down the road, the second app will be a template for an agent to fetch data from an external API whenever that topic gets posted by the first app so port contention will not be a problem if the second app is running by itself someplace.

Comment: Please add the full stack-trace. Also does any of the other processes involved log something useful? Have you enabled tracing/logging of the web calls, so you can better see, what is sent etc?

Answer (score 1):

Add the below value for run the application with the **random port number**.

```
server.port=0
```

Hopefully, you have configured `Eureka` and `Zuul`.